# Row Duplication In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables as bellow. Outline of the four tables given below.

**InventoryTransferHeader**

```
TrasferCode   | TransferDate | FromOutlet|   T0Outlet  
------------- |------------- |---------- |-----------  
SYS000022     |  2016-03-08  |   710     |     707
```

**InventoryTransferLine**

```
TransferCode |ItemCode   |ItemDescription| Qty  
-------------|---------- |---------------|----  
 SYS000022   | 7000000064| ABCD          |   4    
 SYS000022   | 5000000087| PQRS          |   4
```

**InventoryTransferSerials**

```
TransferCode |ItemCode   |SerialNo  
-------------|---------- |-------------  
SYS000022    | 7000000064| 777777777798829  
SYS000022    | 7000000064| 777777777798830  
SYS000022    | 7000000064| 777777777798831  
SYS000022    | 7000000064| 777777777798832  
SYS000022    | 5000000087| 124536850888  
SYS000022    | 5000000087| 124536850889  
SYS000022    | 5000000087| 124536850890  
SYS000022    | 5000000087| 124536850891
```

**Outlets**

```
OutletCode | OutletDesc  
-----------|-------------  
707        | ABC  
710        | XYZ
```

I want my Output as below.

```
TransferCode | TransferDate | FromOutlet | ToOutlet | ItemCode | ItemDescription |SerialNo | Qty  
-------------|--------------|------------|----------|----------|----------------|-------------|--------    
 SYS000022   | 2016-03-08   | XYZ        | ABC      |5000000087|PQRS             |124536850888,124536850889,124536850890,124536850891|4    
SYS000022    | 2016-03-08   | XYZ        | ABC      |7000000064|ABCD             |777777777798829 ,777777777798830 ,777777777798831 ,777777777798832 |4
```

Instead of getting two rows I get eight rows.Here is the code I used.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode,'') AS 'TransferId',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TransferDate,'') AS 'TransferDate',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode,'') AS 'ItemCode',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.ItemDescription,'') AS 'ItemDescription',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferLine.Qty,'') AS 'Quantity',

    STUFF((SELECT '/' + InventoryTransferSerials.SerialNo 
           FROM InventoryTransferSerials
           WHERE InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode =    InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode AND 
           InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode

           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS 'SN',


    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.FromOutlet,'') AS 'outletFrom' ,
    ISNULL(F.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets',
    ISNULL(InventoryTransferHeader.TOOutlet,'') AS 'outletTO' ,
    ISNULL(T.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets' 

FROM    InventoryTransferHeader
    INNER JOIN
    Outlets F ON InventoryTransferHeader.FromOutlet = F.OutletCode
    INNER JOIN
    Outlets T ON InventoryTransferHeader.ToOutlet = T.OutletCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryTransferLine ON InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode = InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryTransferSerials ON InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode 
    AND InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode = InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode


WHERE (InventoryTransferHeader.TransferCode = 'SYS000022')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InventoryTransferSerials ON InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode 
    AND InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode = InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode
```

You already get the serials in the query as SN

You join the InventoryTransferSerials so you have 4 serial numbers  in the table InventoryTransferSerials foreach  InventoryTransferLine row

Comment: Here I only used a  transfer code with multiple serial numbers. But when I filter for a single serial number it displays twice in the serial no column.How can use STUFF() only when there are multiple serial numbers?

Comment: Can you please provide an example, I'm not sure about the question. if you want to filter you can add a condition exists( SELECT InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode 
           FROM InventoryTransferSerials
           WHERE InventoryTransferSerials.ItemCode =    InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode AND InventoryTransferSerials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode 
       and InventoryTransferSerials.SerialNo='124536850888') and you would need to add the filter inside the sub query 'SN'

Comment: OR    you can do an inner join like this  Inner Join
  (
  SELECT  distinct ItemCode,TransferCode
           FROM InventoryTransferSerials
     where InventoryTransferSerials.SerialNo='124536850888'
  ) Serials
  on Serials.ItemCode = InventoryTransferLine.ItemCode AND Serials.TransferCode = InventoryTransferLine.TransferCode

Comment: In above query I have used stuff() to concatenate multiple serial numbers per item code. There can be item code with a single serial number. I want a condition to concatenate serials only if there are multiple serial numbers.Else it should be display as it is.

Comment: The stuff will return a single SN if only one record found.